# How to custom sort sql tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

```
Name  Code  days
-----------------
aaaa   A      2
bbbb   B     -2
cccc   Q     -1
dddd   C      1
eeee   D     -3
ffff   A      3
```

I want to sort this table manually in SQL Sever. When the code is A or Q, it should always be on top. otherwise it should sort by days in asc order.

This is how it should look

```
Name  Code  days
-----------------
aaaa   A      2
ffff   A      3
cccc   Q     -1
eeee   D     -3
bbbb   B     -2
dddd   C      1
```

Comment: What kind of database is it?

Comment: sql database. sorry forgot  to mention

Comment: Sql isn't a kind of database, it's a query language.  What is your DBMS?  Please tag your question appropriately.  There are people here who are knowledgeable on one or more DBMSs but not others.

Comment: Relational database

Comment: That's not what I asked.  Is it SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, something else?

Comment: SQL Server. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` for conditional ordering:

```
select *
from your_table
order by 
    case when code in ('A','Q') then 0 else 1 end,   -- Keep A, Q at top
    case when code is ('A','Q') then code end,       -- order A, Q alphabetically
    days;                                            -- order by days
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables represent *unordered* sets.  You cannot (for practical purposes) sort them.

You can, however, sort the result set from a query.  When querying the table you would do:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (case when code in ('A', 'Q') then 1 else 2 end), days;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name , code , days
from t
order by 
    case when code in ('A','Q') 
    then 0 else 10 + days 
    end asc;
```